# PAUSE PROC IN 8086

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16, proc

Hello I am thinking how to make a simple PAUSE PROC to call it in the main program.
Can you help me?I am using INTERRUPTS for screen ,like int 10h, to show some messages in the screen. 
So I need a simple pause program to call it after my first message  (msg0 db "Press any key to continue...",0) waiting for the user to press any key and then return to the main program to continue.
There should be many ways to do this you are welcome to right any you want but please be simple.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A simple proc.The systems is waiting for you to press any key and continues 
Its simple and it works

```
pause proc

    push    cx
    push    ax
    push    dx
    push    bx

    mov     ah, 08h
    int     21h

    pop     bx
    pop     ax
    pop     dx
    pop     cx

    ret 

pause endp
```